# Lambda function does not retry the sqs message processing in case the Java code throws a runtimeException

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I have a lambda function written in java that listens to sqs events and tries to do some kind of processing on those sqs messages.

As per lambda documentation, if lambda code throws a runtimeException then, lambda would retry the same message twice before it sends it back to the queue. However, I don't see that behavior.
I only see it processing the message just once.

Here is a snippet from the relevant lambda code in this case.

```
@Override
    public Boolean handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context) {

          try{
               ........some queue message processing.....
          }
          catch(Exception ex){
               throw new RuntimeException("exception occurred");
          }

}
```

Is this not good enough for lambda to retry the message 2 more times? I did check the cloudwatch to see what lambda logs and it just has logs from the very first processing only and not the retries.

Can someone tell me what did I miss here because of which it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the throws clause in handleRequest. If you don't have that then, lambda would just swallow the exception

```
public Boolean handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context) throws RuntimeException
```

Other than that, what Thales Munussi has told you about synchronous polling is absolutely right. When you hook sqs with lambda, lambda polls sqs which keeps an open connection between the two hence making it a synchronous connection 
As per aws documentation, lambda doesn’t retry in such synchronous cases. Setting  up a dlq and retires in sqs itself is your best recourse

Keep in mind that lambda would send the message back to the queue after a runtime exception is thrown in your java code 
Based on the redrive setting in your sqs, the sqs will generate the same event based on redrive number.

Once lambda fails to process successfully for redrive number of times, message is sent to the DLQ from the main queue

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html) says it retries two more times if the invocation is *asynchronous*. SQS is a poll-based system. Lambda will poll the Queue and all of its invocations will be **synchronous**.

> For poll-based AWS services (Amazon Kinesis, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon
>   Simple Queue Service), AWS Lambda polls the stream or message queue
>   and invokes your Lambda function synchronously.

What you can do is configure a DLQ on your source SQS queue in case your message fails so you can either analyse it further or process the message again based on the logic you have configured.

**EDIT**

The OP is not able to see the messages in the DLQ for somehow. I have attached images to show it works.

*Lambda sqs-test is triggered by a new message in SQS queue sqs-test*

These are the Queues (sqs-test-dlq is configured as a DLQ for sqs-test).

[image]

This is the code for the Lambda function:

[image]

This is the configuration for sqs-test

[image]

And this is the redrive policy

[image]

After the messages failed in the Lambda function, they were successfully sent to the configured DLQ:

[image]

You must be missing some basic configuration because it works seamlessly as the images above show.

Comment: the way it is configured, lambda has sqs configured and it listens to sqs events. In that case, I assume it is asynch invocation, no ?

Comment: Nope, it’s synchronous. Behind the scenes it’s a polling mechanism, still

Comment: “This consists of Amazon Simple Queue Service. If you configure an Amazon SQS queue as an event source, AWS Lambda will poll a batch of records in the queue and invoke your Lambda function.”

Comment: Polling mechanism i believe would just tell the lamda that a message is ready and lamda is still fetching the message asynchronously. Is that not correct ?

Comment: In any case, when I throw runtimeException, it doesn't even go in the DLQ. I see that sqs just lost the message in case lambda encountered a runtime exception which never went in DLQ as well

Comment: No, it invokes it synchronously. Where did you configure your DLQ? On the Lambda function or on the source SQS queue? It needs to be on the queue and this is easily confused by developers.

Comment: So I think, the question is, why don't i see the message going back to the queue?

Comment: DLQ is on the sqs and not on lamdda

Comment: Also, if I throw a runtimeException in lambda code, is it considered an implicit failure by lambda and it returns the message back to the queue ?

Comment: I have edited my answer with images to prove it works. You must be missing some configuration.

Comment: Looks like lambda doesn't really see the error that I am throwing in my java code and it sees it as a successful message processing even though I throw an error. Not sure how to really throw and exception or error in java that let's lambda see it as an error and send it back to the queue

Comment: No clue then. Sorry.